Filter open time array string data
How to query data to check whether a store is open or not in Laravel.
An example of the return data in the store_open_time column is as follows:
{
  "monday": "10:00-18:00;empty-empty",
  "tuesday": "10:00-21:00;empty-empty",
  "wednesday": "10:00-21:00;empty-empty",
  "thursday": "10:00-21:00;empty-empty",
  "friday": "10:00-21:00;empty-empty",
  "saturday": "10:00-14:00;15:00-19:00",
  "sunday": "10:00-14:00;15:00-19:00"
}

The data format stored in the database is varchar and not timestamp.
With a format like the example above I want to filter the data whether the store is open or not. Example: if I get data at 11 am on Monday, the return is true, if when I get data at 7 pm, the return is false
$getOpenTime = json_decode(MasterStore::find($id)->store_open_time);
$today = strtolower(Carbon::now()->format('l'));
$data = $getOpenTime->$today;
return $this->sendResponse('success', 'Get data success', $data, 200);


status  "success"
message "Get data success"
data    "10:00-18:00;empty-empty"


//  return $data expected
status  "success"
message "Get data success"
data    true


You may split the time slots and do a comparison check to figure out if the store is open or not in the given time slots.
$getOpenTime = json_decode(MasterStore::find($id)->store_open_time);
$today = strtolower(Carbon::now()->format('l'));

$now = Carbon::now();
$openTimes = $getOpenTime->$today;

$data = false;
$slots = explode(';', $openTimes);

foreach ($slots as $slot) {
    $times = explode('-', $slot);

    $startTime = strtotime($times[0]);
    $endTime   = strtotime($times[1]);

    if ($startTime !== false && $endTime !== false) {
        $start = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($startTime);
        $end   = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($endTime);

        if (
            $now->greaterThanOrEqualTo($start)
            && $now->lessThanOrEqualTo($end)
        ) {
            $data = true;
        }
    }
}

return $this->sendResponse('success', 'Get data success', $data, 200);

References:

strtotime
Carbon Comparison
Carbon createFromTimestamp

